# Is it possible to sort user by number of answers/questions

Tags: feature-request

I would like to have the ability to sort users in the "users" tab by the number of answers and number of  questions they asked.

I mean, no just the 'accepted' answers but by total number of answers a user provide and total number of questions a user has asked.

It does not look like it's possible now, so maybe this should be a feature request?

Comment: That's why I don't like to ask questions here. Instead of an intelligent reply I get a downvote. Sure, it's far more easier to just click that down arrow than take a time to take a minute of your presious time to respond. Fine, downvote me like there is no tomorrow.

Comment: Not everyone is going to high five a feature request they think isn't worth it

Comment: Not everyone will like it, sure, it's not the most useful feature, but all the useful features are already implemented, so now its time to add odd features, features that may be interesting to some people.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question. I'm curious where I stand. I ask a lot of questions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is question count league, people could game the system by asking many not-so-useful questions.

And quality is more important than quantity, so may be we shouldn't encourage to ask many questions, IMHO.

Comment: It's not a league, it's not for points or for reputation. It's just so you can see some interesting statistics. I mean, it's probably going to be more useful that all those badges. I mean - badges are great for when you in a boy scout, but we are all adults here. I never ever pay any attention to my or anyone else's badges in SO.